# How to build a queue using Redis where elements of the queue could be swapped?

Tags: database-design, redis, architecture, queue, system-design

I'm building a system that pushes a **unique-id** at the end of the queue with an associated waitlist number. When a user register's to the system they are given a **waitlist** number that is associated with a **unique-id** that is pushed at the end of the queue.

The waitlist number associated with the **unique-id** in the queue is decreased by 1 when a member of the queue is popped from the front of the queue or when a member is promoted in the queue. The queue members are promoted when they perform a certain task(it can be any task that calls the promote function)

The system should have the following functions:-

1. **getWaitlist(id string)**:- The function when called returns the current waitlist number of the member of the queue using the **id**
2. **promoteMember(id string)**:- The function, when called, does two things:-

   1. If the member is **not at the 0th index** of the queue then the member swaps it's waitlist position with the member just ahead of it.
   2. If the member is at the **0th** index of the queue, the member is popped from the queue and its waitlist becomes 0 and the rest of the member's waitlist is decreased by 1.

The solution that I could think of is to use the **Redis list** for building the queue. But the issue that I'm facing is retrieving an element from the queue as using **[LINDEX](https://redis.io/commands/lindex)** takes O(N) time and the index of the element should be known beforehand. Using **[LRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/lrange)** takes O(N) time to fetch all the elements.

There is no way in **Redis lists** to swap elements position, it had to be done separately by fetching the whole list, swapping the elements and pushing it back to Redis, that involves too many operations.

Is there is a better way or architecture or tech stack that I should use to make the system performance efficient?

Comment: I didn't get why do you need to reposition it ? Also instead of LINDEX you may use LPOP

Comment: It's a business requirement to reposition elements in the queue(I don't know if a queue is the best data structure choice for the job). 

Using LPOP won't allow me to fetch an element in the middle of the queue.

Comment: If you need to fetch it from the middle of it, then it is not like a queue. You may take a look on sorted sets. It may cover "almost" each cases of yours.

Comment: Thanks, @Ersoy I'll go through the sorted sets and try to build the system.